# Can I implement Rest Api in this scenario?

Tags: php, android, cordova, rest, restful-architecture

The client is requesting the implementation of an Android App using Rest Api.
I implemented the app using Cordova and it has a connection to the company's server using JSON. The server contains various PHP files which will be executed to retrieve data from database and send it to app, sending email to the user or doing other stuff. 
I don't use web service because there is no web app. The server only store PHP files and the database, which are accesible from Android app. In this case, is it possible to use Rest? and if the answer is yes. Is it recommendable?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use REST.  Yes it is recommendable.

BTW, I would say that you *do* have a "web app" because you do have PHP running via a web server (accepting and responding to HTTP requests).  Just because the PHP is responding with data in JSON format (very lean) and not data wrapped in HTML (fairly verbose) doesn't mean it's not a "web app", at least not by my vocabulary.  Data in JSON is very fashionable (and recommendable) these days, not only for mobile apps but also for client/browser-side apps written in AngularJS, for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer